# Laravel Argon sidebar and navbar problem after Firebase Installation

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, argon

I started a new Laravel project with Argon Dashboard connected to Firebase by using kreait firebase. When first install theme was working correctly but after I installed Krait Firebase, sidebar and navbar started not loading correctly.

This is how it is now.
[image: This is how it is now.]

This is how it should look like.
[image: This is how it should look like.]

I didn't change anything but I checked navbar, sidebar and app blade files, css files and they all seems normal.

Please help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.